# Iterate the whole month in date picker selenium

Tags: java, loops, selenium, datepicker

[The datepicker picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWyv6.png)
I know there are a lot of tutorials regarding date picker. However, they only provide tutorials for a single date on date picker.

What I'm trying to do is to loop through a whole month. For an example, August have 31 day. Thus, instead of providing the date, the user will only have to provide a month and the automation itself will click and move from 1st August to 31st August.

Is there a logic to make it happen? So far I can only do for a single day.

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-calendar"));

    List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//tr"));

    for (WebElement row : tableRows) 
    {
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("//td[not(contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled'))]"));
        for (WebElement cell : cells) 
        {
            WebElement selectday = cell.findElement(By.linkText(cell.getText()));

            Action calendar = builder
                    .moveToElement(selectday)
                    .click() 
                    .click()
                    .build();
            calendar.perform();

            crashPerDay();
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: iterate in a datepicker? you're aware a datepicker is not a loop of any kind, right?

Comment: I know that it is not a loop. That is why I'm asking for a suggestion or some kind of logic that will make this thing happen.

Comment: Try making a single `List` by `List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[...]/td[...]"));` and iterate.

Comment: can you also prive an HTML snippet and picture so that we ca see on what you are clicking

Comment: Why do you have two consecutive click() when building action? Wouldn't doubleClick() serve the purpose?

Comment: @Grasshopper I looked it up on the web that doubleClick doesn't work in chrome (correct me if I'm wrong) and I've tried it myself before (it doesn't work). It detect doubleClick() as a single click. That is why I had to used a two consecutive click()

Comment: @Radclive I could find an open issue with firefox https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/661. Any chance you have the same for chrome. Are you on the latest chromedriver?

Comment: @Westranger I only update the post by adding the picture of the datepicker

Comment: @Radclive: As soon as you will click on one element in the date picker,  the date picker will select that date and will get closed.  For selecting another date, you will again have to open the date picker. Why do you want to select all the dates of the month?The  date picker is used for single date selection not multiple.